# TouchUtils and ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 user event Unit test case not working

Tags: android, testing, junit, android-ndk, touch

Currently I am struggling a little with the Unit test framework...

**what I am trying to do**

- I need to simulate 2 clicks on the screen (100,100) and (400,400) at a small duration difference.
- I need to simulate a longPressClick on the screen Let's say ( 200, 200 )
- Upon User click the native code runs and performs pixel manipulation on Bitmap.
- This test is going to run for multiple pair-sets of points, for analysing the runtime performance of the system

**Here's where I am stuck**

- I am using activityInstrumentationTestCase2 and touchUtils for the user click events.
- TouchUtils.longClickView(InstrumentationTestCase test, View v) works fine ; I'm able to detect the long pressing event propely , But test-case finishes even before the calculation / rendering is complete in my UI thread ; how do I stop the test from exiting in this case ?
- How do i simulate 2 / 3 user clicks @ particular location on screen ? cause TouchUtils.clickView(InstrumentationTestCase test, View v) would only simulate the user click in the center of the screen ... How to do it properly ?

**These are the things I have tried and seems I'm missing out something:**

- TouchUtils.longClickView(InstrumentationTestCase test, View v) works fine...for creating longClickView .. Even I was able to create longClickView() at particular screen location by introducing the timedelay between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP event.. please refer to the code attached
- I was able to achieve the user clicking event at particular screen location , But I faced a strange issue .. When I am displatching the MotionEvent(100,100) from the test-case.. The framework would always add "-76" in the Y event .. not sure why there was this deviation ... I worked around the issue by adding 76 to my input data (100,176) for time being .. did anyone face a similar issue ?
- Even seems with this approach timing is very critical .. as If i place more delay between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP , the event is detected as longClickPress ... and if I put a little less ... the "second" single click events ( ACTION_DOWN + ACTION_UP ) gets detected as DoubleTapEvent ..

What should be the right timing combination for ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN .. for a single user click event simulation .. ????????

```
    @Test
    public void testClick(){
    List<Points> pointSequence = new ArrayList<Points>();
    Log.d(TAG, "FirClick Start Timing : " + SystemClock.uptimeMillis());

    pointSequence.add(new Points(100f,176f));
    pointSequence.add(new Points(100f,176f));       
    singleClickSimulation(pointSequence,false);
    }       

    private void singleClickSimulation(List<Points> pointSequence, Boolean addDelay) {

    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    // NOTE : If I do not place this then the event is detected as doubleTap.
    eventTime += 100;
    Instrumentation inst = getInstrumentation();

    MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, pointSequence.get(0).getX(), pointSequence.get(0).getY(), 0);
    inst.sendPointerSync(event);                
    //eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    pointSequence.remove(0);        

    //This delay I have added just to test; whether there is enough time for pixel manipulation or not, actually it would be used only at the end of the run of all the test cases for single user click
    if(addDelay){
    eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 3000;
    }
    eventTime += 25;
    event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, pointSequence.get(0).getX(), pointSequence.get(0).getY(), 0);
    inst.sendPointerSync(event);
    pointSequence.remove(0);
}
```

Comment: in which way do you perform the double tap event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial Answer :

still to find what's causing the 76px deviation when creating the user click events.

I have been able to simuate the single user click event with 50ms difference propely.
And I had to space 2 clicks by atleast 300ms ; so that "SingleTapConfirmed" can fire on its own for the GeastureDetector class..

```
private void singleClickSimulation(List<Points> pointSequence,boolean addDelay) {

    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    // event time MUST be retrieved only by this way!
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

            // This additional time was added between 2 successive clicks 
            // to make sure that "singleTapConfirmed" event can get fired for "GeastureDetector" class.
    eventTime +=400;
    downTime +=400;
    Instrumentation inst = getInstrumentation();

    MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, pointSequence.get(0).getX(), pointSequence.get(0).getY(), 0);
    inst.sendPointerSync(event);                
    //eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    pointSequence.remove(0);        


            //50 ms timedelay between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP works well      
    eventTime += 50;
    event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, pointSequence.get(0).getX(), pointSequence.get(0).getY(), 0);
    inst.sendPointerSync(event);
    pointSequence.remove(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using TouchUtils, I used.

```
public class TestTouchUtils extends   ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<TheActivity> {

    public void testTouchUtils() throws Throwable {

        final View button = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button)

        getActivity().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                button.performClick();
             }
        });
    }
}
```

It will not update UI on instrument/device, but it will update the variable within the instrument. In my case, the button update the adapter of a fragment.
If I only use,
     TouchUtils.clickView(this, button)
the UI on device is updated, but the variable not updated.

So I combine with TouchUtils too. I don't know why, but it is worked.